# How to do the api call every 10 second even App is killed by user in the IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, api, webview

I am working on a web view app. I want to do an API call after every 10 seconds. How can I call the API in the background even if the app is killed and it is running in the background?

Comment: short answer "You cant", long answer "You cant" :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Okay, thank you. Then how we are receiving the notification in another app (ex: WhatsApp).

Comment: They are triggered by APNS services, not really constant polling, there are multiple way to keep your way active in background but none could guarantee api call every 10 seconds :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari okay I will check another way

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Is It possible to call REST API continuously every 60 seconds when App is Background?

Comment: No you cant, did you read abut various background modes apple provides?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any action(can not compile a single line of code) when the app is killed. you have the control only in foreground and background state of the app.
Notifications can be received even after the app is killed, because notifications are not a part of the app. Notification comes through Apple's push notification servers(triggered by the backend of your app which is still online.)